# Cannot edit an std::atomic value in Visual Studio debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio, atomic

This is my test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<int> Counter = 200;

int main()
{
    if(Counter > 0)
        std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

I'm setting a breakpoint to the `if(Counter > 0)`, and when it is hit I'm adding `Counter` to the watch window:

[image]

As you can see, the "Edit Value" entry is greyed out and it's impossible to change the value in the debugger. Replacing the variable definition with `int Counter = 200;` makes it editable in the debugger, but I lose the associated memory ordering semantics which I need.

Is there a way to create a counter with at least a release-consume ordering which I would be able to manipulate via the debugger?

Comment: I don't know about VS, but in some debuggers you can force the program to issue function calls on demand (e.g. the `call` command in gdb).  If that is available then you could do the equivalent of `call Counter.store(12345)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes add the following to your watch window: Counter._Storage._Value